# Joomshopping in Joomla - Wrong php-file assigned

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, joomshopping

I have a website using three languages, and the website includes a webshop via the Joomshopping component. The translation of the products and all worked, but the things controlled by the joomshop - module (as the label for "go to chart", etc.) are not working for the shopping in french (displayed in english). I thus checked under components/com_jshopping/lang, and weirdly found the following three files:

de-DE.php (setting translations of labels & other general stuff to german)

en-GB.php (setting translations of labels & other general stuff to english)

ru-RU.php (setting translations of labels & other general stuff to russian)

So weirdly, the php-file for russian is in my ftp-server, but not the one for French. When I rename the ru-RU.php-file to fr-FR.php, labels and stuff are displayed in russian when I switch to french in the frontend shop, so that's defo the problem. So; does one of you guys may know why this happened, or does anyone have the fr-FR.php-file for the joomshopping ready under components/com_jshopping/lang; such that I could copy it ?

Cheers!

Comment: You should be able to download the languages from: https://www.webdesigner-profi.de/joomla-webdesign/joomla-shop/downloads/languages.html?lang=en

Comment: @Lodder Cheers buddy, saved me hours of translation work!

Answer (score 2):

So as Lodder answered guys, you can download all the language / translation php-files for joomshop via this link https://www.webdesigner-profi.de/joomla-webdesign/joomla-shop/downloads/languages.html?lang=en (registering (free) required for the download).

unzip the downloaded zip-file of your language, and look for the php-file under JoomShopping-lang-YOURLANGUAGE-YOURVERSION-full / components / com_jshopping / lang. Take it and copy it into your ftp-server on components/com_jshopping/lang, and make sure that the name of the php-file (e.g. fr-FR.php) matches with the language tag assigned to the desired language in joomla (in this case with the tag fr-FR for french).

When I did this it all worked.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted when the system allows you to ;)

Comment: will do, can only do it in two days :D